# Android Equalizer - getBand()

Tags: android, equalizer

I am trying to use the method getBand(), but when the code is running I get the IllegalArgumentException.

```
public void setupEqualizer(){

    equalizer = new Equalizer(0, mediaPlayerSessionId);
    minEQLevel = equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[0];
    maxEQLevel = equalizer.getBandLevelRange()[1];

    band01 = equalizer.getBand(50000);

}
```

The argument of the method getBand is in milihertz, in case I am getting the band that most effects the frequency of 50 Hz.

Why am I get the IllegalArgumentException??

Tks

Comment: Checking the values of `minEQLevel` and `maxEQLevel` would be a good idea. You'll get an `IllegalArgumentException` if you pass a frequency that is below the lower bound of band 0, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Michael, these values are level range expressed in miliBel.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I read that as [getBandFreqRange](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html#getBandFreqRange%28short%29). What I meant is that you should use `getBandFreqRange` to check the lower limit on the first band and the upper limit of the last band before trying to use `getband`.

Comment: @Michael, very strange. I am trying to use getBandFreqRange, but also I am getting IllegalArgumentException (bad parameter value). short numberOfBand = equalizer.getNumberOfBands();
        Log.i("kkk", "Number of Band = "+numberOfBand);
        
        short bandZero = 0;
        int freqRange[] = equalizer.getBandFreqRange(bandaZero);

Comment: @Michael, do you have any clue for me??? tks